# How do I outfile a function?

Tags: c++

I have created a function that creates a Maclaurin series to a vaule x upto N terms. It works fine but now I want this value to be outputted into .txt file. I'm sorry if this is blatetly obvious but I am very new to c++ and have spend hours trying to get the damn thing to work!!

Here is my script;

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;


void Expseries(double x, int N)
{
    int i; // i is loop counter
    double M = 1; // M is individual term in Maclaurin series
    double A = 0; // A is sum of each M terms

    for (i = 1; i <= N; i++)
    {
        M = M*(x / i);

        A = A + M;

    }
    cout << A +1  << endl; 
}
int main()
{
    ofstream jackFile;
    jackFile.open("macout.txt");
    if (jackFile.bad()) {
        cerr << "Error accessing file.";
    }


        jackFile << Expseries(3, 3);


    jackFile.close();
    return 0;

}
```

Can someone please enlighten me and tell me what I'm doing wrong. 
Many Thanks!

Comment: (1) Don't test for `bad`, test general failure, `jackfile.fail()`, and (2) if there is failure, `return`. Also, (3) are you sure you're looking for the file in the right place.

Comment: Note: writing just `if( !jackfile )` is equivalent to writing `if( jackfile.fail() )`

Comment: You are sending the output of the function to the file.  That does not redirect the cout in the function.

Answer (score 0):

your function does not return any thing it just print it to the screen.
edit your function to something like :

```
double Expseries(double x, int N)
{
    int i; // i is loop counter
    double M = 1; // M is individual term in Maclaurin series
    double A = 0; // A is sum of each M terms

    for (i = 1; i <= N; i++)
    {
        M = M*(x / i);

        A = A + M;

    }
    return A+1; 
}
```